# Selenium: upload file to google drive using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-drive-api, selenium-chromedriver

My question is about uploading some files to Google drive using Selenium.

It seems if I use the "upload" button in Google drive, Selenium cannot manipulate the OS Window popped out.

Therefore, I want to use Selenium to automate the "drag and drop" action, but the itemUploadDrop area is  so I cannot send files to it. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you!!

Comment: These two questions are different. For the link you paste, they are trying to solve the upload from button or input tag. In Google drive clearly that cannot be done. My question is about the "drag and drop" area in Google drive and how to achieve upload through that.

Answer (score 0):

There is hidden input

```
<input type="text" id="drive_hist_state" name="drive_hist_state" style="display:none;">
```

Try using sendKeys on that element.

Or use [google drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

There is an examples inside.

Comment: Thank you but this element cannot deal with uploading files. I believe Google Drive SDK would work

Comment: No problem @Carl, let us know if there is something else to help. Good Luck